# What does "how not to speak" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Consider this sentence.

> Americans consider themselves egalitarian and unsnobbish about accents, but they are full of notions about how not to speak.

What does "how not to speak" mean? I know the meaning of "how to speak"; it means asking about which method I should take to speak.

Does "how not to speak" mean trying finding a way to avoid saying something?

Answer (score 7):

There is an inherent ambiguity in the *how not to* expression. It can mean *how to avoid mistakes when doing something* or *how to avoid doing it at all*. Generally, the ambiguity is resolved by the context of the expression, so in the OP's example, it will be interpreted as the former. Whereas:

- This article will advise you on how not to get pregnant

will be interpreted as the latter; namely, *how to avoid getting pregnant at all*, not *how to avoid mistakes when getting pregant*. Conversely:

- This article will advise you how not to ask for a raise

will be interpreted as *how to avoid mistakes when asking for a raise*, not as *how to avoid asking for a raise at all*.

- This article will advise you how not to react to provocation.

could have either of the two meanings.

Answer (score 3):

*How not to speak* means how people should not speak. For example, people should not speak too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

It tells us that they know what and they should not speak. Eg. they should not speak in a volume that is not audible to others, or not in a harsh tone, or not in a manner that hurts the other person.